# Setting explicit response Content-Type in CouchDB

Tags: json, couchdb

I'm looking for a way to set the `Contet-Type` for couchdb response.

I have `POST` a JSON using `Content-Type` and `Accept` request headers as `application/json`. But when I call the `GET` for that document, it returns the JSON response with `Content-Type` `text/plain; charset=utf-8`. What I'm expecting is getting `application/json` as it's `Content-Type`.

How can I do this?

**POST**

- URL : http://localhost:5984/hotel_staticdata
- Request Body :
  `{"_id":"test-hotel-stat-data","content":[{"hotelcode": "AMB3_LON","hotelname": "Ambassadors Bloomsbury"},{"hotelcode": "ALE1_LON","hotelname": "Alexandra"},{"hotelcode": "ALE1_LON","hotelname": "Alexandra"}]}`
- Request Headers : 
  Accept : application/json
  Content-Type : application/json

**GET**

- URL :  http://localhost:5984/hotel_staticdata/test-hotel-stat-data
- Response Body : `{"_id":"test-hotel-stat-data","_rev":"3-6c6e26cd5690794886a8dc65308bf078","content":[{"hotelcode":"AMB3_LON","hotelname":"Ambassadors Bloomsbury"},{"hotelcode":"ALE1_LON","hotelname":"Alexandra"},{"hotelcode":"ALE1_LON","hotelname":"Alexandra"}]}`
- Response Headers : 
  Content-Length : 249
  Content-Type : **text/plain; charset=utf-8**

Instead of this, I tried PUT then GET also but the results is same.

- CouchDB version : 1.6.1

Answer (score 5):

I got the answer.

When I call the GET with `Accept:application/json` request header. It works! 
Damn! How did I miss it!

Anyway, If you have any different solution please feel free to post.